# array for errors in class

Tags: php, validation

I want to make an array that will contain error strings so that I can output them if their is an error on the form.

But I keep getting this error `Cannot use [] for reading in` anyone know how to make an array for this kind of thing?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
class users {
...
public $errors = array();



//VALIDATE THE USERS INFO
function setError($error) {
    $this->errors = $error[];
}
//check the passwords match
function checkPasswords($pass1, $pass2){
    if($pass1 !== $pass2) {
        setError("Your passwords dont match");
    } else {
        $this->password = $pass1;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there... the square brackets go on the left of the equals sign, so `setError` should be:

```
function setError($error) {
    $this->errors[] = $error;
}
```

Well that and in `checkPasswords` you should call `setError` as:

```
$this->setError("Your passwords don't match");
```